# Определение числа с наибольшей суммой цифр

Tags: python, функции

Даны три целых числа. Определить, у которого из них больше сумма цифр. Подсчет суммы цифр организовать через функцию.

Сумму цифр числа я определяю так:

```
while n>0:
    d=n%10
    n=n//10
    sum+=d
```

А как организовать через функию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def sumdigits(n):
    sumd = 0
    while n > 0:
        n,d = divmod(n, 10)
        sumd += d
    return sumd

items = [123, 567, 899, 999]

res = max(items, key=sumdigits)

print(res)
#999
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def sumdigits(n):
    return sum([ int(i) for i in str(n) ])

items = [123, 567, 899, 999]
res = max(items, key=sumdigits)
print(res)
999
```

Answer (score 4):

Суммирование в функциональном стиле:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))

items = [123, 567, 899, 999]
res = max(items, key=sum_digits)
print(res)  # 999
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = 111
b = 222
c = 333

def max_sum_digits(*args):
    return (lambda x: x[max(x.keys())]) ({sum([int(i) for i in str(n)]): n for n in args})

print ( max_sum_digits(a,b,c) )
```

Comment: Думаю, вам минус поставили из-за слишком нагроможденного кода. Попробуйте его отрефакторить -- например на отдельной строке найти тот словарь. И вместо лямбды лучше вручную выполнить код